# Get the classname of child element

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get the class name of a child element using JS. I've tried the following, but it won't work. Any help is much appreciated!

```js
var selectedicon = document.getElementByClassName('selected-icon');
var iconclass = selectedicon.getElementsByTag("i")[0].className;

console.log(iconclass);
```

```html
   <div class="selected-icon">
   <i class="hummma"></i></div>
```

Comment: Reading [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName) is always useful.

Comment: I'll just note that neither of those elements has the class `channels`, and neither of those methods exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want the `class` of the first `i` inside the first `selected-icon` element. If so:

```js
var i = document.querySelector(".selected-icon i");
console.log(i ? i.className : "Not found");
```

```html
<div class="selected-icon">
   <i class="hummma"></i>
</div>
```

`document.querySelector` accepts a CSS selector and finds the first element in the DOM that matches it. There's also `document.querySelectorAll` which returns a list of matching elements. There are versions of both of them on elements as well, which only look within that element's descendants.

Answer (score 1):

Try it:

```
var selectedicon = document.querySelector('.selected-icon');
var iconclass = selectedicon.children[0].className;

console.log(iconclass);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use **`document.getElementsByClassName`** and **`selectedicon.getElementsByTagName`**.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder what do you mean? [link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp)

Comment: @JonathanYanivBenAvraham: The answer was originally incorrect. It's been fixed now. (Now it's still largely incomplete, but not incorrect. :-) )

Comment: @T.J.Crowder oh okay, sorry I thought you had meant that there was no such method to get an element by class. Nevermind :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var part = document.querySelector(".selected-icon");
var chld = part.querySelector('.hummma');
console.log(chld.className);
```